# How can I export all typescript types in a namespace individually?

Tags: typescript

I'm using `@types/googlemaps`. I have an `index.d.ts` file that looks like:

```
/// <reference types="@types/googlemaps" />
declare module 'googlemaps'
```

In my application, I can type things like:

```
const setLatLng(latLng: google.maps.LatLngLiteral) => { ... }
```

This works fine. But, I like to have all of my imported types at the top of the file, i.e.:

```
import { LatLngLiteral } from 'googlemaps'

const setLatLng(latLng: LatLngLiteral) => { ... }
```

This doesn't work: `Cannot use namespace 'LatLngLiteral' as a type.`

I can re-export these types with a file like this:

`my-types.ts`

```
export type LatLngLiteral = google.maps.LatLngLiteral
```

Then `import { LatLngLiteral } from './my-types'`

That works! But there are dozens of types, and I'd prefer to not have to re-export all of these manually. Is it possible to do something like:

`my-types.ts`

```
export * from 'googlemaps' // doesn't work
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is something that was updated since you checked, but the [docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/using-typescript) now say to use `google.maps`, not `googlemaps` (I've seen the DefinitelyTyped project also includes `google-maps` and `google_maps`, besides the two just mentioned..)

So I found this question because I was having the exact came problem, but with `google.maps`, after some toying around, I got it working:

As with the docs, I have in my `tsconfig.json`:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "...": "...",
    "types": [
      "google.maps"
    ]
  },
}
```

Besides that, what caught me out and it looks like you're trying to do the same, I was trying to import just the `LatLngLiteral` type directly, which didn't work.

```
// DOESN'T WORK
import { LatLngLiteral } from 'google.maps';
const x = y as LatLngLiteral

// DOES WORK
// no need for import statement with compiler options configured...
const x = y as google.maps.LatLngLiteral
```